# Modals of obligation in the past

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, obligation

Can you say 'You needn't have to go' instead of 'You needn't have gone'?

Answer (score 1):

"Have to go", in any tense, will be interpreted with the sense of "have to" = "obliged to". So "You needn't have to go" is very unlikely to occur, as it means "you are not obliged to be obliged to go".

In order to get a past sense from "have" it must be followed by a past participle, such as "gone".